# Как работает округление числа вверх до кратного?

Tags: c++, математика, битовые-операции

Вычитал в одной статье технику, которая позволяет округлить число X в большую сторону так, чтобы оно было кратно Y.

```
int roundup(int x, int y) {
    return ((x+y-1) & ~(y-1));
}

int main() {
    int x = 1020; // number to round up

    x = roundup(x, 512);

    return 0;
}
```

Этот пример кода округляет X до 1024, однако нигде не объясняется что происходит в функции roundup, поэтому прошу у вас объяснения по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это работает при округлении до степеней двойки, а не до любого числа. Впрочем, такое округление нужно часто.

```
(x+y-1)
```

увеличивает число x так, чтобы получилось число, не меньше кратного y (включая x!), но не достигающее следующего кратного. Например, при y=4

```
8 + 3 = 11       8<=11<12 
9 + 3 = 12       12<=12<16 
10 + 3 = 13      12<=13<16 
11 + 3 = 14      12<=14<16 
12 + 3 = 15      12<=15<16 
13 + 3 = 16      16<=16<20
```

Инверсия

```
~(y-1)
```

при этой операции над числом `y=2^k` в скобках получается бинарное число с хвостом из единиц, причем количество этих единиц соответствует степени двойки `k`

```
4-1 = 3 = 0b00000011
```

А при его инверсии получается число из единиц с хвостом из `k` нулей.

```
~0b00000011 = 0b11111100
```

При выполнении операции AND обнуляется `k` последних бит, вот и получается кратность `y`

```
14 = 0b00001110
0b00001110 &  0b11111100 = 0b00001100 = 12
```

Про более универсальный вариант с целочисленным делением-умножением Harry уже написал

Answer (score 3):

Секрет в `&~(y-1)`, который обнуляет биты в конце, т.е. по сути выполняет деление на `y` с последующим умножением на него же и обеспечивает результат, кратный `y`.

```
int roundup(int x, int y) {
    return ((x+y-1)/y*y);
}
```

Кстати, этот вариант будет работать и для других `y`, не только степеней двойки.

Comment: Зачем вы отклонили правку? У вас ответ непопорядку структурирован )

Comment: @Kromster Потому что он отражает главное - принцип. А то, что такой код работает для всех y - дело второе. Мне казалось, мы уже как-то договаривались, что мы взаимно не замечаем один другого?  :)

Comment: Я лишь поменял местами 2 и 3 части, текст полностью ваш. 1 часть - вы отвечаете на вопрос. 2 часть вы предлагаете/описываете лучший вариант, 3 часть - непосредственно код/реализация. Сейчас же порядок несколько путанный, когда после объяснения особенности из вопроса вы приводите какой-то другой код. Уверяю вас, на ваш ник я совершенно не смотрел, +/- не ставил :)

Comment: `int z = x + y - 1; return z - z % y;`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тоже работает, и даже лучше  :) Но не по тому принципу, как в коде у ТС. Именно поэтому я в ответе привел код, отвечающий на вопрос "как это работает" (а уже потом заметил, что он работает и для других значений — вопрос-то был не в этом..)